# Given a DOI, how can I programmatically obtain all the author affiliations?

Tags: affiliation, databases, doi

Given a DOI, how can I programmatically obtain all the author affiliations? The coding part isn't the issue, but finding a proper database/API is.

E.g. for DOI [10.1186/s12920-019-0598-0](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6936069), the author affiliations are:

> 1. Department of Mechanical Engineering, University of Saskatchewan, Saskatoon, S7N 5A9 Canada
> 2. Division of Biomedical Engineering, University of Saskatchewan, Saskatoon, S7N 5A9 Canada
> 3. School of Mathematics and Statistics, Hainan Normal University, Haikou, 571158 China

Comment: If you are asking how to write a computer program for this, you are at the wrong place.

Comment: @Buffy I'm looking for an API or dataset. I'll add the database tag.

Comment: Maybe the [Crossref REST API](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc) can be used for this. Do note that some [affiliation data may be missing](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc/issues/4) though.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, the main sources of citation data are:

- Proprietary data sources:

  - Google Scholar
  - Scopus
  - Web of Science (WoS)
- Open access data:

  - Crossref
  - MEDLINE (focusing on medical papers)

Some papers compare the comprehensiveness between these different sources, e.g. see {1,2}.

---

To extract the author affiliations given a DOI, a few options (search for "affiliations" on the links below) :

1. https://support.datacite.org/docs/api-get-doi
2. https://www.nlm.nih.gov/bsd/licensee/elements_descriptions.html (MEDLINE database https://www.nlm.nih.gov/bsd/medline.html)
3. https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc  suggested by [Anyon](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/17254/anyon).

---

For option 3 (CrossRef API), one can use the https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc  API via the Python library https://gitlab.com/crossref/crossref_commons_py:

```
# If testing in Docker
docker run --interactive --tty ubuntu:18.04 bash
apt update; apt install -y git nano wget htop python3 python3-pip unzip

# Requirements
pip3 install crossref-commons

# Python code
import crossref_commons.retrieval
crossref_commons.retrieval.get_publication_as_json('10.5621/sciefictstud.40.2.0382')  # affiliations are empty
crossref_commons.retrieval.get_publication_as_json('10.1148/radiol.2018180887')       # affiliations are present
```

though it seems that quite often authors have no affiliations on CrossRef.

My guess is that MEDLINE (option 2) has more thorough metainformation (I based my guess given the information I see on the PubMed website, which relies on MEDLINE database, e.g. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6936069/ has author affiliations, but not `crossref_commons.retrieval.get_publication_as_json('10.1186/s12920-019-0598-0')`, even though 10.1186/s12920-019-0598-0 = PMC6936069. [Anyon](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/17254/anyon)'s comment also questions CrossRef's comprehensiveness for the author affiliations field). The MEDLINE database can either be downloaded or accessed via API (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/home/develop/api/). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62974197/395857 on how to access the MEDLINE database in Python.

---

If one cannot find the affiliation in the metainformation and if the PDF can be obtained from the DOI, one could use PDF-to-text extraction programs for scientific papers, such as:

- https://github.com/kermitt2/grobid (has the ability to parse affiliation and address blocks)
- https://github.com/allenai/science-parse
- https://github.com/allenai/spv2

---

To test [`pybliometrics`](https://github.com/pybliometrics-dev/pybliometrics) that [BND](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/87690/bnd) refers to in their [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/151890/452):

```
# If testing in Docker
docker run --interactive --tty ubuntu:18.04 bash
apt update; apt install -y git nano wget htop python3 python3-pip unzip

# Install and configure pybliometrics
pip3 install pybliometrics
from pybliometrics.scopus.utils import config
config['Authentication']['APIKey'] = '' # Enter Elsevier API key obtained on http//dev.elsevier.com/myapikey.html

# Retrieve author affiliations
from pybliometrics.scopus import AbstractRetrieval
ab = AbstractRetrieval("10.1016/j.softx.2019.100263")
from pybliometrics.scopus import AuthorRetrieval
au1 = AuthorRetrieval(ab.authors[0].auid)
print(au1.affiliation_current)
```

Unfortunately pybliometrics relies on Elsevier Scopus's API, which isn't free: some institutions have subscribed to it, but fewer and fewer are willing to feed the Elsevier sharks.

---

References:

- {1} Harzing, Anne-Wil, and Satu Alakangas. "Google Scholar, Scopus and the Web of Science: a longitudinal and cross-disciplinary comparison." Scientometrics 106, no. 2 (2016): 787-804. https://web.archive.org/web/20170922223941/http://eprints.mdx.ac.uk/18511/1/gsscowos.pdf
- {2} Van Eck, Nees Jan, Ludo Waltman, Vincent Larivière, and Cassidy Sugimoto. "Crossref as a new source of citation data: A comparison with Web of Science and Scopus." A blog post in the website of the Centre for Science and Technology Studies (CWTS), Leiden University, URL: https://www.cwts.nl/blog (2018). https://www.cwts.nl/blog?article=n-r2s234 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200718205848/https://www.cwts.nl/blog?article=n-r2s234))

Comment: FWIW I think some journals give free personal subscriptions to Scopus as a reward for reviewing?

Comment: @BenBolker I don't review for paywalls or parasites ;-)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/pybliometrics-dev/pybliometrics
The example on the github page is quite close to what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, this looks great! Unfortunately pybliometrics relies on Elsevier Scopus's API, which isn't free. (and my institution hasn't subscribed to the Elsevier sharks).